# Redshift UDF boto sql query and S3

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, udf

Is there a way to use UDF in Redshift, execute a SQL query and upload the result to AWS S3 ? Would really appreciate if someone knows how to this.

Thanks

Comment: UDF works with compute nodes and generally executes against each column & row combination. not sure why do we wanted to combine compute function with data extract?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question -- are you wanting to "execute a SQL query and upload the result to S3" within the UDF itself? Please Edit your question to provide more details of what you wish to do.

Answer (score 0):

To create a UDF in Redshift, you can [use python](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/user-defined-functions.html). You can then call the function in a SQL SELECT statement. To output the results of a query to a file in S3, you can use the [UNLOAD](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) statement.